# Adding milliseconds to Time Stamp in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am having an issue with my time stamp management. In my dataset I have two variables, namely, Time and Relative Time. Time is in HH:MM:SS.ss format while relative time is numeric variable containing amount of seconds passed since 0 (i.e. 0.76, 1.28, 1.78, 2.38 ... ). For simplicities sake lets consider the hypothetical situation:
`Time <- c("09:33:23.00", "09:35:25.00", "09:36:26.00")`
`RTime <- c(0.78, 1.28, 3.98)`
Then I do the following to add the milliseconds to the time:
`ATime <- strftime(strptime(Time,format="%H:%M:%OS")+(RTime %% 1),format="%H:%M:%OS2")`
I would like it to result in:
`"09:33:23.78" "09:35:25.28" "09:36:26.98"`
But instead I get the following:
`"09:33:23.77" "09:35:25.27" "09:36:26.98"`
Its only one millisecond off most of the time. And i don't understand why its doing that. I could add 0.01 in the `strptime` function, i.e. `(RTime %% 1) + 0.01`. But I don't find that very elegant and more importantly, as you can see in the above example, its not always 0.01 off - as with the last case. Any hints as to what is happening, or perhaps suggestions to improve code?
Cheers
*[SOLVED]*
**EDIT:** For the interested. This is how I eventually solved my problem:
`ATime <- strftime(strptime(Time,format="%H:%M:%OS")+(RTime %% 1)+0.005,format="%H:%M:%OS2")`
This 'forces' the rounding instead of truncating which leads to the difference in milliseconds.
Thanks to  @Josh O'Brien and @nrussell for their comments!

Comment: I believe this (at least the part about *why* it's happening) is [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8889554/980833)

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but I think the issue is explained in the `strptime` helpfile, about 70% down from the top (2 paragraphs after the `% V` passage: `Note that %S ignores (and not rounds) fractional parts on output.`. You can see this by doing `strftime(strptime(Time,format="%H:%M:%OS")+(RTime %% 1),format="%H:%M:%OS3")`

Comment: Thanks! To be honest, half hour posting my question, i found this [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-May/064211.html). Before posting I had tried very hard to find an answer, but I wasn't getting anywhere. So a bit embarrassing :P. Thanks a lot for the comments! At least I know why now.

Comment: @tstev -- And if my experience is any guide, that's not a coincidence! At least half the time I've written a question up here, I *finally* figure out the answer myself while/because I'm doing the writing. Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7726034/210673 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15383057/210673 may also be of interest

Comment: @Aaron - Thanks for the links, they are indeed very useful links. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889554/milliseconds-puzzle-when-calling-strptime-in-r/8890813#8890813) (and by @nrussel in comments above) this is caused by `strftime()`'s truncation (not rounding!) of the machine's slightly imprecise floating point representation of fractional seconds.

As a perhaps slightly kludgy fix, you could write a small printing function that adds a very small value -- greater than `.Machine$double.eps` but less than `.01` -- to each time value before printing it.

```
strftime2 <- function(x, ...) {
    strftime(x + 1e-6, ...)
}

## Compare results
strftime(strptime(Time,format="%H:%M:%OS")+(RTime %% 1),format="%H:%M:%OS2")
# [1] "09:33:23.77" "09:35:25.27" "09:36:26.98"
strftime2(strptime(Time,format="%H:%M:%OS")+(RTime %% 1),format="%H:%M:%OS2")
# [1] "09:33:23.78" "09:35:25.28" "09:36:26.98"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! Its also what I eventually found - people suggested force rounding by adding 0.005 for example. Appreciate the comments!