# lubridate package assignments involving thousandths of a second

Tags: r, lubridate

Why does the `ymd_hms` function from R's lubridate package return "2018-01-09 15:43:44.843 UTC" for `ymd_hms('2018-01-09T15:43:44.844Z')`?

I naively would have expected "2018-01-09 15:43:44.844 UTC".

`ymd_hms('2018-01-09T15:43:44.822Z')` returns "2018-01-09 15:43:44.822 UTC".

Since this is GMT/UTC, I don't believe daylight savings would be a factor, and different values for the `truncated =` option don't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

From the ymd_hms documention:

> NOTE: The ymd family of functions are based on strptime()

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889554/milliseconds-puzzle-when-calling-strptime-in-r/), the issue seems to lie in how strptime truncates rather than rounds fractions of a second. Play around with `options(digits.secs = n)` to see how it handles various numbers of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use:

```
format(strptime("2018-01-09T15:43:44.844Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz = "EST"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3 %Z", tz = "EST") 

[1] "2018-01-09 15:43:44.844 EST"
```

Note that the milliseconds are passed in the format using the argument `%OS`