# Date-Time Conversion in R with fractional seconds

Tags: r, date, time

How to convert the string

```
t <- c("00:00:0.00", "00:00:0.34")
```

into a number?
tried several approaches - but none of them worked..

Comment: You could convert to an arbitrary date first or use `lubridate`...

Comment: how to convert to date/number was actually my question..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basic idea is to convert your character string to a valid `POSIX*t` object, and then convert that to a `numeric` value:

```
## Set a couple of printing options
options(digits = 12)
options(digits.secs = 3)

## Convert from character to POSIXlt to numeric
(a <- strptime(t, format="%H:%M:%OS", tz="GMT"))
# [1] "2013-04-09 00:00:00.00 GMT" "2013-04-09 00:00:00.34 GMT"
(b <- as.numeric(a))
# [1] 1365465600.00 1365465600.34
```

Note that, when converting back from numeric to `POSIX*t`, there are floating point issues that can change how those objects are printed. ([See here for more discussion of that issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds))

```
## It _looks_ like you've lost 1/100 second on the second time object
(c <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(b), origin = "1970-01-01", tz="GMT"))
# [1] "2013-04-09 00:00:00.00 GMT" "2013-04-09 00:00:00.33 GMT"

## Here's a workaround for nicer printing.
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(b+1e-6), origin = "1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
# [1] "2013-04-09 00:00:00.00 GMT" "2013-04-09 00:00:00.34 GMT"
```

Comment: +1 What's the motivation for the extra parentheses, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde -- They just force printing of an object's value, even when it's been assigned to an symbol. (Compare `x <- rnorm(5)` and `(x <- rnorm(5))`. I put them there b/c I generally want my answers to be self-contained and runnable by copy and pasting them from SO into an R session, although I can see that they're a little distracting ;)

Comment: no criticism at all. asked because I expected to learn something...and I did! thanks.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde No problem. I didn't take it as criticism, and recall wondering the same thing myself once, back in the mists of time...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: The `"%S%OS"` part gives me trouble when the number of "full" seconds is larger than zero -- but `"%OS"` works. I understand that `"%OS"` matches both integer and fractional parts of the second.

Comment: @krlmlr -- Woah. Thanks for the great catch! Fixed now.