# When generating a list of times and dates in R as.posixct %OS3 is outputting "NA" but %S works

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct

I am trying to generate a list of dates and times at 0.0625 second intervals from a given date and time using lubridate and at.posixct. When I use a whole second value I have no issues, but when I try and use %OS3 to get decimal seconds it outputs NA NA NA.

```
z <- seq(1, length.out=nrow(ctd1), by=1)
calendarTime <- as.POSIXct("2023-11-04 01:40:46.111", 
                           format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz='UTC') +  
lubridate::period(0.0625,'second') * z  
print(calendarTime)

[1] "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC"
[5] "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC"
[9] "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC"

calendarTime <- as.POSIXct("2023-11-04 01:40:46.111", 
                           format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3", tz='UTC') + 
lubridate::period(0.0625,'second') * z  
print(calendarTime)

[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[39] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[77] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I tried various iterations of this including changing the date format as well as updating XQuartz and R and reinstalling tidyverse but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: The input format is just `%OS` not `%OS3`. Previous discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906584/date-time-conversion-in-r-with-fractional-seconds

Comment: Thanks for this. I did try that, but with %OS it still doesn't print a decimal second, just rounded up to the whole.

calendarTime <- as.POSIXct("2023-11-04 01:40:46.111", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz='UTC') + lubridate::period(0.0625,'second') * z  
[1] "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC"
   [5] "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC" "2023-11-04 01:40:46 UTC"

Comment: As per the linked question, you need to change the printing options in R to show the extended partial seconds by default. The `calendarTime` object definitely stores the fractional part, see `dput(calendarTime)` and `difftime(as.POSIXct("2023-11-04 01:40:46.111", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz='UTC'), calendarTime)`

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now. That works. Thanks!