# Bizzare as.POSIXct behavior for some time stamp with time part dropping

Tags: r, posixct

I was struggling that read.csv with colClasses containing POSIXct was rounding up entire timestamps column down to date dropping time part. I came across a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30039313/673826) suggesting that some date I have may miss time part. That was not the case. However, after bisecting my vector, I noticed that some particular time stamps are to blame. Here is a snippet.

```
as.POSIXct(c("2016-03-13 01:00:00", "2016-03-13 02:00:00", "2016-03-13 03:00:00"))
```

That yields to me

```
[1] "2016-03-13 CST" "2016-03-13 CST" "2016-03-13 CST"
```

It is around DST transition, but nevertheless where is time part? Is it a bug?

```
> version
               _                           
platform       i386-w64-mingw32            
arch           i386                        
os             mingw32                     
system         i386, mingw32               
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.0                         
year           2016                        
month          05                          
day            03                          
svn rev        70573                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
nickname       Supposedly Educational
```

**Update**

While [setting time zone globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6408072/673826), seems to overcome the problem, it still looks like a bug to me.

**Update 2**

I confirm that behavior is Windows specific (platform specific bug?) here is the output from R 3.2.3 on Ubuntu

```
[1] "2016-03-13 01:00:00 CST" "2016-03-13 01:00:00 CST"
[3] "2016-03-13 03:00:00 CDT"
```

**Update 3**

There is a [known unconfirmed bug #16852](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16852).

**Update 4**

Unless I'm missing something, there is no difference in my case between %S and %OS as mentioned in the comment.

```
> strptime(c("2016-03-13 01:00:00", "2016-03-13 02:00:00", "2016-03-13 03:00:00"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2016-03-13 01:00:00 CST" "2016-03-13 02:00:00"     "2016-03-13 03:00:00 CDT"
> strptime(c("2016-03-13 01:00:00", "2016-03-13 02:00:00", "2016-03-13 03:00:00"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2016-03-13 01:00:00 CST" "2016-03-13 02:00:00"     "2016-03-13 03:00:00 CDT"
```

P.S. I didn't dig into the code yet... :/

Comment: I doubt it's a bug. Due to DST, the datetime `"2016-03-13 02:00:00"` doesn't actually exist. It literally never happened. So `as.POSIXct` is probably just trying to be consistent in what it returns across the vector. Note that changing just that element to `01:59:59` works.

Comment: @joran I wouldn't complain if it just gave me an error, or turned that into 01:00:00 with whatever time zone. But to silently drop time part...., took me quite some time to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Well, I'm also fairly certain that most of these low-level datetime functions in R are simply using system level tools specific to your OS. So you may have Windows to blame, not R.

Comment: As I'm digging through `as.POSIXlt.character` I'm beginning to reconsider my initial reaction to this...

Comment: ...specifically, compare the effect of `strptime` on your vector using a format of either `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` or `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"`, the latter of which is what is eventually hit in `as.POSIXlt.character`, called from `as.POSIXct.default`. The `%OS` format is documented at the end of the Details section of `?strptime`.

Comment: Interesting. On my platform (OS X) it works with `%S` but with `%OS` is removes the times completely.

Comment: On Windows 7, I can see that `lapply(c("2016-03-13 01:00:00", "2016-03-13 02:00:00", "2016-03-13 03:00:00"), as.POSIXct, tz="America/Chicago")` doesn't strip the times from the 1st and 3rd entries. Strange that it would give a different result when treated separately instead of together.

Comment: The R bug #16852 started via discussion on [data.table issue 1619](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1619).