# How to get milliseconds using as.POSIXct or as.POSIXlt in r?

Tags: r

I want to get subseconds so I use following:

```
> options(digits.secs=6)
> as.POSIXlt(df1$Global.Time[5]/1000, origin="1970-01-01",  tz="America/Los_Angeles")
[1] "2005-06-15 07:53:42.7 PDT"
```

Why does the output not contain something like "07:53:42.700000"?

Same problem with `POSIXct`:

```
> as.POSIXct(df1$Global.Time[3]/1000, origin="1970-01-01",  tz="America/Los_Angeles")
[1] "2005-06-15 07:53:42.5 PDT"
```

Comment: Check out Aaron's `myformat.POSIXct` function in [his answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7730759/640595).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this (corrected per Frank's direction):

```
 d <- as.POSIXct(Sys.time())
 format(d,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")
 [1] "2015-05-30 18:06:08.693852"
```

Comment: Oh, I see I was in too much of a hurry. Ok, will delete it. Your tip is clearly better.

Comment: If you change it to this:  `format(d,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")` it would work.

Comment: Would you be annoyed if I did that :)