# R convert factor into numeric

Tags: r, character, numeric

How can I change this to numeric values, the number refers to the record of the 1.5km running, containing min:sec:one-tenth of seconds

```
"4:04.86"  -> 4:04.86
```

as.numeric function is not working in this case, I think, its because of ':'

Comment: `4:04.86` is not a number. What is your desired output?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds)

Comment: this is the record of the running, containing minuite second and one tenth of second. When I identify the number by str() it appears as factor

Comment: please `dput` a sample of your data in the post.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way with **lubridate** that gives the result in seconds.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- "4:04.86"
period_to_seconds(ms(x))
# [1] 244.9
```

Comment: Error in period_to_seconds("4:05.85") : 
  trying to get slot "minute" from an object of a basic class ("character") with no slots

Comment: You can't leave out the the call to `ms` ...

Comment: I'm sorry but what is ms?

Comment: Please read my answer more closely. You need `period_to_seconds(ms("4:05.85"))`

Comment: I don't want that to be returned as 244.9, I just want it to be the exact same number without the quotes

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You mean the strings have quotes in them? Are you just looking for `gsub('"', '', x)`?

Answer (score 3):

Base R can handle this a-okay too, using `?as.difftime`:

```
as.difftime("4:04.86", format="%M:%OS")
#Time difference of 4.081 mins

as.difftime("4:04.86", format="%M:%OS", units="secs")
#Time difference of 244.86 secs
```