# Formatting a SQL Server Datetime into %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS4 %z format via T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I am being requested by a vendor to convert a SQL Server `DateTime` value into the following specific timestamp format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS4 %z`. The query will be placed into their software to query my database.

The desired output seems like it might be vaguely related to this [posixct question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds) in R; but this is about output in SQL Server. I have been provided no specific errors other than the field is appearing in their software as blank but it works in my SQL interface.

The output I am getting from SQL is like the following:

```
2016-03-16 00:00:00.000
```

The output of another column that comes like this they have no problem `varchar(30)` with `2016-03-16 11:34:36` as it just treats it as a string WHEN mapped into a string field.. but for it to treat it needs to be in the referenced `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS4 %z` format.

The differences seem subtle other than the data type but even when mapped into a string field it is failing to map the SQL native output into once of its fields.

I have tried for example

```
cast(convert(datetime, tn.last_settled, 126) as Varchar(30))
```

on the `datetime` but that results in `Jan  1 1990 12:00AM` and not the desired format.

How do I get to the desired string `2016-03-16 11:34:36` and datetime `2016-03-16 00:00:00.000` formats into the required `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS4 %z` format from a SQL Server `datetime` format in T-SQL?

Comment: It sounds like they've written their application to parse a string instead of getting working with datetimes (perhaps they're coming from a database that didn't handle datetimes natively). What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @lc. I am running SQL 2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012 and above, you should be able to use [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) with a standard .NET formatting string to give them the output they need. For example:

```
FORMAT(tn.last_settled, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm:ss.ffff')
```

To turn your string *input* into a datetime, you should be able to use [`PARSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx):

```
PARSE(@theStringValueTheySendYou as datetime)
```

Comment: If I lower case the year (yyyy vs. YYYY) that worked for the datetime, but not the string. I had to do a convert on the string paired with that to get the  second part to work. `FORMAT(convert(datetime,tk.last_start_date,126), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm:ss.ffff') `

Comment: @CRSouser Sorry yes, lowercase y