# How do I round a POSIXct to the nearest millisecond?

Tags: r, timestamp

Following on from: [How R formats POSIXct with fractional seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds), I have two distinct (character) timestamps that are converted to the same POSIXct value using `fastPOSIXct` from the `fasttime` package:

```
library(fasttime)
tmpstmp <- c("2010-03-01 12:41:52.713",
             "2010-02-01 12:41:52.714")
options(digits.secs = 6) # note that this is required to display fractional seconds in R.    
fastPOSIXct(tmpstmp)
```

giving

```
> fastPOSIXct(tmpstmp)
[1] "2010-03-01 23:41:52.713 AEDT" "2010-02-01 23:41:52.713 AEDT"
```

which is very undesirable behaviour. My workaround is to concatenate 10 microseconds, so that I now have

```
tmpstmp <- c("2010-03-01 12:41:52.71301",
             "2010-02-01 12:41:52.71401")
```

giving

```
> fastPOSIXct(tmpstmp)
[1] "2010-03-01 23:41:52.71301 AEDT" "2010-02-01 23:41:52.71401 AEDT"
```

I would now like to round this POSIXct object down to the nearest millisecond. How do I do this?

Comment: `fastPOSIXct(tmpstmp)` on my machine doesn't even show the milliseconds: `"2010-03-01 12:41:52 GMT" "2010-02-01 12:41:52 GMT"` - have you set something somwhere? fasttime: Version: 1.0-1

Comment: A common pitfall with R timestamps! Does `options(digits.secs = 6)` work for you?

Comment: It's the same in base R: `options(digits.secs = 3);
as.POSIXct("2010-02-01 12:41:52.714", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "GMT")`, which probably means it's a floating point issue in the underlying OS libraries.

Comment: The precision at the millisecond level should be a floating point issue indeed.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?