# I am not able to get all the 9 decimal digits in R . it is going only upto 6digits

Tags: r, strptime

This should be the output: 20/2/06 11:16:16.123456789
But my output is "2006-02-20 11:16:16.123456 IST"

```
z <- strptime("20/2/06 11:16:16.123456789", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS")

z # prints without fractional seconds

op <- options(digits.secs = 9)

z
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds

Comment: @MrFlick I have tried that and still didn't work. Only upto 6 digits even then.

Comment: Don't think this is a duplicate of the other question. It has to do with the floating point precision, which is about 16-17 digits. See the output of `print(as.numeric(z),digits=22)`. In short: a double has not enough precision to represent more than 6 seconds digits.

Comment: @nicola It is not giving me the correct ouput even then.

Comment: There is a discussion of precision there. And `z` happens to be POSIXlt in this case. `print(z$sec, digits=10)` does return more digits, but yeah, not exactly the same for floating point reasons. But yea, all the R formatting stuff is capped as 6 decimal digits according to `?strptime`

Comment: @MrFlick you are right, being a `POSIXlt` offers a little more room for the seconds. The answer is the doc you are reporting.

Comment: Try also `paste0(strftime(z,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),":",z$sec)` to have a bunch of other digits.

Comment: @nicola thanks for this. This is exactly what i wanted .