# Change column format to POSIXct in R

Tags: r, posixct

I have a dataframe consisting of 3 cloumns. I want to change the format of the of the Datetime column to POSIXct. But i can't figure out a way to work with the milliseconds. Is it even possible to work with milliseconds in POSIXct? I have seen it in different posts

**This is a sample of the dataframe I am working with:**

If I first try to set the format to `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"` I loose the milliseconds:

```
#data
df
                  Datetime                                                           Tag      Value
1  2023-09-27 00:00:00.032        RobotSignals_RobotIR01LoadingUnloadingComIn_di_Lifebit   1.000000
2  2023-09-27 00:00:00.033        RobotSignals_RobotIR01LoadingUnloadingComIn_di_Lifebit   1.000000
3  2023-09-27 00:00:00.068                                     SystemTrack_ActivePowerL1 682.399960
4  2023-09-27 00:00:00.075                                     SystemTrack_ActivePowerL2 573.800000
5  2023-09-27 00:00:00.082                                     SystemTrack_ActivePowerL3 551.600000
6  2023-09-27 00:00:00.088                                       SystemTrack_AirPressure   5.426357
7  2023-09-27 00:00:00.094                                         SystemTrack_CurrentL1   3.577860
8  2023-09-27 00:00:00.102                                         SystemTrack_CurrentL2   3.161120
9  2023-09-27 00:00:00.102 RobotSignals_RobotIR03L3POSpringLoadingComIn_di_JobNoMirrored  10.000000
10 2023-09-27 00:00:00.108                                         SystemTrack_CurrentL3   3.389500

#changing the format from charakter to POSIXct
df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

#data without the milliseconds
              Datetime                                                           Tag      Value
1  2023-09-27 00:00:00        RobotSignals_RobotIR01LoadingUnloadingComIn_di_Lifebit   1.000000
2  2023-09-27 00:00:00        RobotSignals_RobotIR01LoadingUnloadingComIn_di_Lifebit   1.000000
3  2023-09-27 00:00:00                                     SystemTrack_ActivePowerL1 682.399960
4  2023-09-27 00:00:00                                     SystemTrack_ActivePowerL2 573.800000
5  2023-09-27 00:00:00                                     SystemTrack_ActivePowerL3 551.600000
6  2023-09-27 00:00:00                                       SystemTrack_AirPressure   5.426357
7  2023-09-27 00:00:00                                         SystemTrack_CurrentL1   3.577860
8  2023-09-27 00:00:00                                         SystemTrack_CurrentL2   3.161120
9  2023-09-27 00:00:00 RobotSignals_RobotIR03L3POSpringLoadingComIn_di_JobNoMirrored  10.000000
10 2023-09-27 00:00:00                                         SystemTrack_CurrentL3   3.389500
```

And if I try to directly follow OS by 3 `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3"` the values change to NA.

```
#changing the format from charakter to POSIXct
df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")

#all values changed to NA
   Datetime                                                           Tag      Value
1      <NA>        RobotSignals_RobotIR01LoadingUnloadingComIn_di_Lifebit   1.000000
2      <NA>        RobotSignals_RobotIR01LoadingUnloadingComIn_di_Lifebit   1.000000
3      <NA>                                     SystemTrack_ActivePowerL1 682.399960
4      <NA>                                     SystemTrack_ActivePowerL2 573.800000
5      <NA>                                     SystemTrack_ActivePowerL3 551.600000
6      <NA>                                       SystemTrack_AirPressure   5.426357
7      <NA>                                         SystemTrack_CurrentL1   3.577860
8      <NA>                                         SystemTrack_CurrentL2   3.161120
9      <NA> RobotSignals_RobotIR03L3POSpringLoadingComIn_di_JobNoMirrored  10.000000
10     <NA>                                         SystemTrack_CurrentL3   3.389500
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only looks like you're losing the milliseconds.  They don't print, but are retained.  You can see when you take the difference between two values.  From the printed output, it looks like all the differences should be zero, but you can see below that the differences are as you would expect from the differences in the milliseconds.

```r
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Datetime,                                                           ~Tag,      ~Value,
"2023-09-27 00:00:00.032",        "RobotSignals_RobotIR01LoadingUnloadingComIn_di_Lifebit",   1.000000,
"2023-09-27 00:00:00.033",        "RobotSignals_RobotIR01LoadingUnloadingComIn_di_Lifebit",   1.000000,
"2023-09-27 00:00:00.068",                                     "SystemTrack_ActivePowerL1", 682.399960,
"2023-09-27 00:00:00.075",                                     "SystemTrack_ActivePowerL2", 573.800000,
"2023-09-27 00:00:00.082",                                     "SystemTrack_ActivePowerL3", 551.600000,
"2023-09-27 00:00:00.088",                                       "SystemTrack_AirPressure",   5.426357,
"2023-09-27 00:00:00.094",                                         "SystemTrack_CurrentL1",   3.577860,
"2023-09-27 00:00:00.102",                                         "SystemTrack_CurrentL2",   3.161120,
"2023-09-27 00:00:00.102", "RobotSignals_RobotIR03L3POSpringLoadingComIn_di_JobNoMirrored",  10.000000,
"2023-09-27 00:00:00.108",                                         "SystemTrack_CurrentL3",   3.389500)

dat$Datetime <- as.POSIXlt(dat$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
round(dat$Datetime[2:10]-dat$Datetime[1:9], 3)
#> Time differences in secs
#> [1] 0.001 0.035 0.007 0.007 0.006 0.006 0.008 0.000 0.006
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

There does seem to be a bit of floating point weirdness going on, but if you round to their original precision (as above) the results are right.

Comment: Thank you checking out the data! You are right, the milliseconds aren't lost.

I have read about the rounding error on another post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds)